# Not able to set Text from fragment class to Main class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TextView finalcost;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;

        initUI();

    }

    private void initUI() {

        fragment = new HomeFragment();

                 finalcost.setText= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fc);




        if (fragment != null) {
            seletedTopbar(1);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment).commit();
        }

    }

    public void setfinalcost(int cost)
    {
        finalcost.setText(String.valueof(cost));
    }
}
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    MainActivity ma ;
Button btn

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
                false);

        context = getActivity();

         ma = new MainActivity();


        initUI(rootView);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void initUI(View view) {

      btn = (Button)view.findViewByid(R.id.clicked);

      btn .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                  int cost = 100;
          ma.setfinalcost(cost);


            }
        });


     }
```

Now when I trying to call that method and pass the value then it will force close the app.

When I click on button that at that time the values is passed to MainActivity method. and it passes perfect.

But it is force close on  `finalcost.setText(String.valueof(cost));`

How can I solved this?

Comment: what does the  console say.. something like (null pointer exception)??

Comment: You have to declare your TextView on your onCreate as follows : finalcost =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fc); **(That was the mainfly problem)** and then on the initUI on your MainActivity() you should remove the findviewbyid from your finalcost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace  `ma = new MainActivity();` with `ma = (MainActivity)getActivity();`.

Comment: May i know the difference between        `ma = new MainActivity();` and        `ma = (MainActivity)getActivity();` ?